# socket.io functions' emit(), on() first parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Why isn't it possible to pass the first argument as variable containing the string?

on server side:

```
    var aux = 'word';
    io.sockets.emit (aux, source);
```

and then on client side:

```
    var justme = 'word';
        socket.on (justme, function () {
    });
```

I know I can achieve the same with:

```
    io.sockets.socket(id).emit('msg', 'just-you');
```

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. Are the *word*s the same on the client and server? Any error messages?

Comment: no error. on() method does not 'fire' in my example with justme variable. If I put a string literal 'word' instead of **aux** in the emit() method and instead of **justme** in the on(), then, of course, it works.